# Kotlin structuring classes for ~3000 lines JSON (de)serialization - accessibility/storage?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

just recently made the switch from java to kotlin, what i'm having troubles with is how to structure/nest my data classes correctly in kotlin.
I need to parse a json string of roughly 3000 lines.

Sample Data:

```
{
"OBJECT1": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0,
    "Property_6": 0,
    "Property_7": 0,
    "Property_8": 0,
    "Property_9": 0,
    "Property_10": 0,
    "Property_11": 0,
    "Property_12": 0,
    "Property_13": 0,
    "Property_14": 0,
    "Property_15": 0,
    "Property_16": 0,
    "Property_17": 0,
    "Property_18": 0,
    "Property_19": 0,
    "Property_20": 0
},
"OBJECT2": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0
},
"OBJECT3": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0,
    "Property_6": 0,
    "Property_7": 0,
    "Property_8": 0,
    "Property_9": 0,
    "Property_10": 0,
    "Property_11": 0,
    "Property_12": 0,
    "Property_13": 0,
    "Property_14": 0,
    "Property_15": 0,
    "Property_16": 0,
    "Property_17": 0,
    "Property_18": 0,
    "Property_19": 0,
    "Property_20": 0,
    "Property_21": 0,
    "Property_22": 0,
    "Property_23": 0,
    "Property_24": 0,
    "Property_25": 0,
    "Property_26": 0,
    "Property_27": 0
},
"OBJECT4": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0,
    "Property_6": 0,
    "Property_7": 0,
    "Property_8": 0,
    "Property_9": 0,
    "Property_10": 0,
    "Property_11": 0
},
"OBJECT5": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0,
    "Property_6": 0,
    "Property_7": 0,
    "Property_8": 0,
    "Property_9": 0,
    "Property_10": 0,
    "Property_11": 0,
    "Property_12": 0,
    "Property_13": 0,
    "Property_14": 0,
    "Property_15": 0,
    "Property_16": 0,
    "Property_17": 0,
    "Property_18": 0,
    "Property_19": 0,
    "Property_20": 0,
    "Property_21": 0,
    "Property_22": 0,
    "Property_23": 0,
    "Property_24": 0,
    "Property_25": 0,
    "Property_26": 0,
    "Property_27": 0,
    "Property_28": 0,
    "Property_29": 0,
    "Property_30": 0,
    "Property_31": 0,
    "Property_32": 0,
    "Property_33": 0,
    "Property_34": 0,
    "Property_35": 0,
    "Property_36": 0
},
"OBJECT6": {
    "Property_0": 0,
    "Property_1": 0,
    "Property_2": 0,
    "Property_3": 0,
    "Property_4": 0,
    "Property_5": 0,
    "Property_6": 0,
    "Property_7": 0,
    "Property_8": 0,
    "Property_9": 0
},
"OBJECT7": {

    "DEFAULTOBJECT1": {
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 50,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 0.8,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 2,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 0.25,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 16.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 500,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 3,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 3,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 75,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 50,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT2": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 0,
        "Default_Property3": 200,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT3": {
        "Default_Property1": 1,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 50,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 0.35,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 0.25,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT4": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 100,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT5": {
        "Default_Property1": 1,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 60,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 5.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 0.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 1
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 6,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 4.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 0.2,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 15.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT6": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 200,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT7": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 200,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 50.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT8": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 200,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    "DEFAULTOBJECT9": {
        "Default_Property1": 0,
        "Default_Property2": 1,
        "Default_Property3": 200,
        "SUBOBJECT1": {
            "Suboject1_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property2": 6,
            "Suboject1_Property3": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property5": 100,
            "Suboject1_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property7": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property9": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property10": 256,
            "Suboject1_Property11": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property12": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property22": 1,
            "Suboject1_Property23": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property25": 1.0,
            "Suboject1_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject1_Property28": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT2": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property6": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property7": 2.0,
            "Suboject2_Property8": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property9": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property10": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property11": 1.0,
            "Suboject2_Property12": 1000,
            "Suboject2_Property13": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property14": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property15": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property16": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property17": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property18": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property19": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property20": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property21": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property22": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property23": 60,
            "Suboject2_Property24": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property25": 100,
            "Suboject2_Property26": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property27": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property28": 1,
            "Suboject2_Property29": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property30": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property31": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property32": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property33": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property34": 0
        },
        "SUBOBJECT3": {
            "Suboject2_Property1": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property2": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property3": 100.0,
            "Suboject2_Property4": 0,
            "Suboject2_Property5": 0
        }
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...

  }
}
```

Its pretty much a big object that contains 6 objects that only have properties mostly integer/floats, the 7th objects is nested pretty heavily -> list of "defaultObjects", which has 2/3 properties and 3 "subObjects". The "subobjects" all have tons of properties.

I would need for this data to be accessible in different fragments, lets say each of the 7 objects is associated with one fragment in a viewPager/tabLayout.

Java implementation is just simple singleton that gets initialized once from the deserialized JSON and stays in memory aslong as the user is accessing the data. 
Probably not the best performance-wise since its a pretty big object.

Would love to hear a few opinions on how to implement a solution in kotlin, handle the access to the data etc.

cheers

Comment: Nothing will be big if you organize the backend database carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Kotlin version of singleton](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations).

About the object itself, I don't really think that that's an issue, actually. Of course, the smaller the object – the better, but frankly, in your case, I would consider using HashMap instead of class for this case, as all your classes just have bunch of weird named properties

Comment: The Json is literally just an example and the properties will be named properly at a later stage. Currenly im getting the instance of the singleton in every fragment that needs access, you reckon the approach is alright? I don't really want to pass the object around all the time, thats why i initially chose a singleton. Cheers